# Want to add water filter supply line after water shutoff valve but can't get adapter to fit

Tags: plumbing, sink, shutoff, adapter

I just bought this [adapter](https://amzn.to/444vqdV) and for some reason, it won't fit with 3/8 or 1/2.
[image]
[image]

Any recommendations that would fix the issue? I am not sure what my water line size and from what I know, 3/8 and 1/2 are standards. Is there any specific parts that I'm missing?

My current shutoff valve:
[image]

My current supply hose:
[image]

Comment: I'm trying to connect additional water outlet for my RODI. I bought this product: https://ibb.co/bW0Nw4h this product has 1/2 and 3/8 thread that won't even fit in my water line

Comment: Here is the product link: https://amzn.to/3L8CIoh   with specifications.

Comment: I am trying to connect my RO/DI water filter system. my RODI uses 1/4 tubing which is no problem. the Issue im having is that the product i bought https://amzn.to/3LelR3t with 3/8 and 1/2 thread won't even fit in my under sink water line. Not sure what standard size is my under sink water line thread.

Comment: Photo of that fitting, and knowing which country you are in, might be helpful. In the US, I _think_ the flexible tubing that runs from the cut-off valve to the sink is usually a 3/8" Compression fitting at the cut-off valve and 
1/2"  Iron Pipe (FIP / IPS) connection at the faucet. What you need, if attaching this to one end or the other if that hide, is fittings on both sides that match one or the other if those sizes, unless you want to replace other parts too

Comment: Re: "for some reason, it won't fit with 3/8 or 1/2." What exactly do you mean by "won't fit"? If in the US, your shutoff valve outlet is normally 3/8 or 1/2 compression and your faucet inlet is normally 1/2 or 3/8.  Your photo of your shutoff valve and supply hose *look* like 1/2 inch.

Comment: What is the approximate diameter of the outside of the nut on your braided water supply hose end? For a 1/2" the widest outside diameter of the nut should be barely over 1 inch.

Comment: Put your photos and all other information in your question, please, not down here. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: i believe i need 1/2 pipe thread and 1/2 in the hose thread type of valve adapter but with 1/4 tubing for my RODI

Answer (score 1):

To put it where you want it, it has to be the same size and thread on both sides, since you're inserting it into an existing connection.

From the diagram, if you bought the right size unit, they expect you to use the adapter ring to fit one side it the other, depending on whether your existing fitting is 1/2" or 3/8". The adapter should either screw into the hose or onto the valve.

If it doesn't fit either way I'd say you have the wrong version of this add-on valve and need to figure out what size you pipe fittings actually are are. Something metric?

Comment: it won't fit using 3/8..might be 1/2

Comment: i measured the thread in the pipe and its 0.67 inches. not sure if that is the standard